# Buffer overflow return address with null byte, workaround

Tags: windows, buffer-overflow, aslr

I'm practicing Buffer Overflows using Free Float FTP Server 1.0 on Windows 7 SP 1. I have done simple `jmp esp` examples on Windows XP, where system DLLs are without rebase or Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR).

I'm now trying to write a Buffer Overflow for Windows 7, where I haven't gotten any system DLL with rebase or ASLR disabled. I can still exploit it, but it won't survive reboot. As such, I'm very much left with opcode from the FTPServer.exe, but they all use low stack addresses (`0x0040xxxx`) and they all end with a NULL byte (e.g. `0xCE 11 40 00`) and hence terminate my exploit.

What are the options now? Is there a workaround to the NULL bytes in the addresses I want to use? More specifically, I want to know whenever there is an option to use NULL bytes at the end of an address if it is listed as a bad character.